# "Called object type NSString is not a function or function pointer" error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.cellIdentifier = [self.brain returnCellIdentifier:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.brain enchantmentCellText:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error.  The error seems to come from the line that my cursor is on.  How can I fix this error:

```
Semantic issue
Called object type 'NSString *' is not a function or function pointer
```

Comment: Please just put the text into the body of the question. The only thing the screenshot does is make it hard to read.

Comment: Why do you have a property `self.cellIdentifier`? That could juts be a local variable.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right line? The implication here is that you have code like `foo(bar)`, where `foo` is expected to be a function/function pointer, but is in fact an `NSString*`.

Comment: I fixed it.  It turns out I forgot a comma in another file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had this exact same error and discovered it was caused because I had created an array manually by typing out all of it's elements, and had forgotten a comma in between two of them.

Comment: That was also my problem.  It took me hours to figure out why my code wasn't working.  I don't know why Xcode didn't warn me about the comma.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you have that error, but if you don't have a need for the cell identifier to be different (which it doesn't appear you do) you may want to change that line your cursor is on to the more standard:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

which would change your other lines to something closer to:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

The error itself may come from the method of your "brain" object that your calling.  If you post that we may be able to tell.

~ Good Luck

Comment: changing the line to static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell" works.  I just need to be able to change the cellidentifier dynamically